# How to manage a million records?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I really need an expert's help to answer my query.

Here is the scenario:

Im using an sql select query to retrieve a million records.
I need to perform sorting and grouping on the resultant records which im storing in a datatable( in one execution)
and looping through it for grouping and sorting it.
I know this is so childish and not the  right way to process it.
How can i manage the million records effectively and apply the grouping and sorting to it?

Really need help out here. Heard of executing the select query batch wise but how to implement the grouping and sorting while we dont have the entire data in hand?
I cannot go for sql order by and group by directly and that's against my requirement.

## Here is what i'm doing right now:

I have the following objects, i.e the column names for grouping and Sorting

```
List<Group> groupList;
List<Sort> sortList;
DataTable reportData; // Here im having the entire records from db
```

Im looping through the 'reportData' row by row and matches the current and previous row for the custom grouping and sorting. Would like to know how the same can be done when we are using a batchwise execution or any alternative solution is there?

Comment: You can group locally using linq to sql functions: `OrderBy` and `GroupBy`

Comment: If you can't do sql grouping/sorting, then you'll have to do it clientside, which means you'll have to slurp the entire result set into the client app. Hope you've got enough ram to hold a million records like that.

Comment: Moreover its not a good practice to get hold of million records at a time in application; better is you manipulate it using stored procedures on SQL Server side  and then fetch the records.

Comment: maybe you could provide some minimal example in code or pseudocode.

Comment: Yes, to know your idea behind getting million rows would be helpful answering your question.

Comment: I'm not having my code with me right now. I'd updated with what im doing. Please go through it

Comment: Which would be the best practice? To use a list or a datatable to keep this much data?

Comment: Get the data only which you require using View, Functions or Stored procedure on SQL Server Side. You need to post different question to get answer for tackling million rows.

Comment: One word: [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging).

Answer (score 4):

> I need to perform sorting and grouping on the resultant records which
>   im storing in a datatable( in one execution) and looping through it
>   for grouping and sorting it.

What for?

Seriously.

Do not pull then try plaing smart with a stupid object model behind (and datasets are not particularly smart, sorry).

Group and sort in your select statement, pull the data lready grouped and joined and be done with it.

A million records was a small amount of data for sql server when the original version was release (4.2 it was, a port of sysase sql server) 17 years of so ago. These days it is something that fits likely into the processor thiird level cache and is nothing a proper sql server even realizes it has just processed.

SQL is particulaly good ad doing projects and ever since they indoruced MARS you can even run multiple queries over one connection, which comes in handy here.

So, go back - throw away the dataset and "I try to program a sort algo" and create proper SQL statements to pull the data as you need it.

Comment: But the case is, in my application, user will need to display some fields and sort based on another. this cannot be done using sql i guess. then how can i do that?

Comment: It can. NOONE sayxs the SQL has to be hardcoded. You as a programmer have to do your job - that is put together the SQL (betterin the form of a LINQ statement) dynamically on demand depending on user input. Capable progarmmers hve done so ever since SQL was created, you know. Which has a good chance to be longer than you live (SQL is quite ancient actually). Noone says you can not construct a SQL Statement dynamically based on a query form.

Comment: a spell check is in order here

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should implement [Partition Pruning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-pruning.html). Partitioning will allow for a separation of content like you are requesting in order to have faster queries.

Comment: With millions of records? You must be joking. Partitions are great, but they only are great when you have data. Millions is hardly something sql server even realizes it has. BILLIONS - ok. Millions - nothing to get smart.

Comment: @TomTom : Partitions would still help improve the time query takes, right? You're only saying improvement would be small and probably not worth it, right? But then it's entirely subjective, improvement of 100 ms would be small for many apps but for real time systems it can mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, in your case, I would create a temporary database table with the structure I want especially to cover my grouping.

Then I would select the records from main tables and insert them to the temporary one appying all modifications including grouping.

A specific index on how you want them sorted should be also applied.

After that, just select from this table, do what you have to do, and finally if the data are not needed any more, delete the temporary table.

I would choose the above solution because a million of records in memory smells trouble to me...

Comment: This is not possible at all. because im connecting to a database where i dont have the write permission. Only select query can be fired on it.

Comment: Ok then memory is your only chance. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

For example:

**1. Lets assume that you would like to group them by their DocumentTypeID**

```
var groupByType = reportData.GroupBy(g=>g.DocumentTypeID);
```

**2. Sorting Alphabetically**

```
 var sortAlphabetically = reportData.OrderBy(g=>g.DocumentName);
```

**3. Grouping and Sorting**

```
var groupAndSort = reportData.GroupBy(g=>g.DocumentTypeID)
                             .OrderBy(g=>g.DocumentName);
```

**4. Sort and Group**

```
var groupAndSort = reportData.OrderBy(g=>g.DocumentName)
                             .GroupBy(g=>g.DocumentTypeID);
```

**5. Multiple Grouping and sorting**

```
var multipleGroupAndSort = reportData.GroupBy(g=>g.DocumentTypeID)
                                     .GroupBy(g=>g.CreatedOnDate.Month)
                                     .OrderBy(g=>g.DocumentName);
```

so on and so forth...

But I would still discourage bringing million rows to application. It will cost memory. There are of course ways to manage it through stored procedures etc.

Comment: I'll be having multiple levels of grouping and sorting. I'll be grouping based on a Type,say DocumentType and sorting based on DocumentName, within that itself, i'll be grouping based on the DocumentCreatedonMonth and sort based on Date. How will that be done using the lamda expression?

Comment: Thank you Marshal for the guidance. Need to try all the suggestions you people had given. I would like to kno whether it's good to use datatable or a list to keep for example a 10k records?

Comment: @NewBie: List stores single column, datatable have multicolumns. Choice will be based on how many columns you want.

Comment: What if i can create a resultant object dynamically and keep it as a list<Object> ? will it make any difference then?

Comment: just use `var` for storing result, if you are unaware of return type.